# Nuget resource change from https to http

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server, nuget-spec

I try to upload a NuGet package but a receive this error:

An error was encountered when fetching 'PUT http://nuget_domain/api/v2/package/'. The request will now be retried.

But in the https://nuget_domain/v3/index.json is 'https://nuget_domain/api/v2/package'

Y want to know why it tries with http with it is configurated with https and how to fixed.

Regards

Comment: What  does your push command look like? Did you add the username, password for your private nuget feed?

Comment: Did you use `nuget.exe`cli or `dotnet.exe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) First**, please use the latest `nuget.exe cli v5.7.0` from [this link](https://www.nuget.org/downloads). Download it into the local path. And then copy its path into **System Environment Variable** `PATH` so that it can be called from **CMD**.

**2) Second**, run this command under CMD to add your private nuget package source with `username` and `password` into the global `nuget.config` file. When you push a nuget package by CMD, it will read the file first so that you don't need to add some extra instructions.

**Before that**, you should pay attention to your nuget sever path. Make sure that the link is right, you can also type the path into website to check whether it could return something.

```
nuget sources add -Name "nuget path" -Source "https://nuget_domain/v3/index.json" -username "xxxx" -password "xxxx"
```

add your username and password of the private nuget sever.

**If** you want to update this nuget source, you could run:

```
nuget sources update -Name "nuget path" -Source "xxxx" -username "xxxx" -password "xxxx"
```

**3) Third**, then push the nuget package like this,

```
nuget push xxx\xxx.nupkg -Source "nuget path"
```

**Besides**, if it still does not work, please try to use **Step 2** to change your nuget package source to `https://nuget_domain/`. Not sure whether it works and hint from [this github link](https://github.com/loic-sharma/BaGet/issues/293).

====================

If you use dotnet to push a nuget package, you could use this command:

```
dotnet push xxx\xx.nupkg -s https://nuget_domain/v3/index.json --api-key xxxx --skip-duplicate
```

Comment: The project was not mine, it was configurated to upload the package to the server when the project is being building, fortunately the error shown the push command as you described (incluiding the ApiKey), just a little modifies to dotnet to work.  Thanks.